# Google Drive API for Android upload file but can't sync to remote

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

After I upload file, I can select from my application. But it doesn't sync. It doesn't exist in the Google Drive App.

I checked the sha1 and package， it has no problem. The log tell me nothing. I also google it. No one has this problem.

I use [the sample](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/quickstart) to demonstrate this problem.

After I import this project, I install it on my phone, It can't login my account. So I create Oth

In this sample, I just add one Oauth2.0 for it, as below:
[image]

Then the sample can login with my account and take a picture and display the save file view of Drive API for Android. But It didn't sync to remote.

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not clarify the problem. I added the sample code.